# Excel how to find real random data set from mean and standard deviation?

Tags: excel, random, mean

In Excel it is easy to find the mean and standard deviation given 10 single data points.  But is it possible to generate 10 random data points in Excel given the mean and standard devation?

In Excel I can right click "View Code" and access a macro to use macro coding, but how would I go about coding this?

```
Sub rand()
  Range("B4").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B4").Calculate
  Range("B4").Value = Range("B4").Value
  Range("B5").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B5").Calculate
  Range("B5").Value = Range("B5").Value
  Range("B6").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B6").Calculate
  Range("B6").Value = Range("B6").Value
  Range("B7").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B7").Calculate
  Range("B7").Value = Range("B7").Value
  Range("B8").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B8").Calculate
  Range("B8").Value = Range("B8").Value
  Range("B9").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B9").Calculate
  Range("B9").Value = Range("B9").Value
  Range("B10").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B10").Calculate
  Range("B10").Value = Range("B10").Value
  Range("B11").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B11").Calculate
  Range("B11").Value = Range("B11").Value
  Range("B12").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B12").Calculate
  Range("B12").Value = Range("B12").Value
  Range("B13").Formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$B$14,$B$15)"
  Range("B13").Calculate
  Range("B13").Value = Range("B13").Value
End Sub
```

This is my random data generated based on mean and std dev, then i will use this data to find mean and std dev, if the mean and std dev did not mean the value i want then redo until it correct, so what code i need to add to make it redo?

Comment: In general, you cannot reverse-engineer 10 points of data given only the standard deviation and mean.

Comment: I know how to do it in other programming like JAVA but in excel i dunno, in java can use random generate data until it meet the right mean and std dev... then accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without VBA:**

Say we want a set of values with a mean of **7** and a std-dev of **.005**

In **A1** through **A20** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

this is the data we must transform to meet our requirements.  In **B1** enter:

```
=A1*0.005/STDEVP(A:A)
```

and copy down through **B20**.  The values in column **B** will have the desired std-dev.

In **C1** enter:

```
=B1+7-AVERAGE(B:B)
```

and copy down through **C20**.

Column **C** will have both the correct std-dev and correct mean:

[image]

**With VBA:**

Perform exactly the same technique, but use arrays rather than columns of cells.  It is equally easy to generate sample data for Poisson, LogNormal, etc. distributions.  Here is some simple code to put 20 values in column **G:**

```
Sub ForcedDistribution()
    Dim ary(1 To 20) As Double
    Dim bry(1 To 20) As Double
    Dim cry(1 To 20) As Double
    Dim mean As Double, std As Double
    Dim i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    Randomize
    mean = 7#
    std = 0.005

    For i = 1 To 20
        ary(i) = Rnd
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 20
        bry(i) = ary(i) * std / wf.StDevP(ary)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 20
        cry(i) = bry(i) - wf.Average(bry) + mean
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 20
        Cells(i, 7).Value = cry(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```